# Add header to webrequest asp.net

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

I am trying to add a token to a webrequest but failing message being : Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters.
Token is : `"ZN4oXXYJQ3WIdMBKR2uENi2AtE5hAocH0P3/MIBaHZA=ksRnVWCpGFw4kWagzkUfg7RXzps="`

Fails when I try to add the header like this:

```
req.Headers.Add("X-ApiKey: ",sToken);
```

Do I need to base64 encode this? Or what else am I missing?
Thank you.

Comment: I hope that's not a real token!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for base64. You just do not need to add colon to the header name. This colon is what makes header name invalid. You were probably following standard notation `headerName: headerValue`, but `WebRequest` will handle that formatting for you, you just need to provide the actual name and the value. So correct code should be:

```
req.Headers.Add("X-ApiKey", sToken);
```